# How to access cookies with React Native Expo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, cookies, expo

I'm fairly new to React Native and Expo, and I'm confused about how cookies are managed. I have an Express server that sets a token cookie in a response (`res.cookie("jwt",token)`). Somehow when my React Native client makes an authentication request and receives a response, the client stores the cookie somewhere, and the token is passed in future requests (with `credentials: "include"`), until I restart the emulator. My main questions are

- Where are these cookies stored?
- How can I access them?
- I was under the impression that React Native doesn't really support cookies. Is this functionality specific to Expo?
- If I were to deploy this as a real mobile app, can I rely on this cookie behavior, or should I use one of the React Native cookie management packages?

Thank you in advanced for your help!

Comment: instead of using cookie, consider storing the JWT token using AsyncStorage

Comment: Definitely on my mind! Thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ReactNative does not have this support by default as it runs on the native side (well, you do have support on the WebView component but that's isolated)

If you are relying on Expo they are still figuring out the cookies management, you can follow the updates in this issue, they are aware about the persistence of cookies been inconsistent between app loads:

https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/6756

If you have to use the cookies anyway I would suggest to use this lib, it seems quite stable, but maybe you will need to implement some integrations with your API yourself:

https://github.com/react-native-cookies/cookies

Wish success on your project.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the links! I'll probably use one of the cookie packages or async storage

Comment: What will you do if you store cookies in async storage? Setting cookie header is impossible client side on web. Is it possible on android/ios client side to set the cookie header when sending request?